# Best way to keep url in angular without doing build process

Tags: c#, typescript, plsql, angular9

I have my apiurl in my constant.cs file like

```
export class Constants {
     public static apiURL: string = "http://localhost:50563//api/";  
     public static tokenExpiryTime:number=120;//This valuse is in minutes.
}
```

Now i used to build every time as my machine IP changes ,
For build i use command "ng build  --prod --base-href /my-app/"
Can someone please let me know a better solution without doing a build ?

Thanks.

Comment: One of possible ways is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: yes thanks ,i need like the way you shared in .net same in angular cli ,from angular calling my api methods so i need a IP .